# text box submits empty html tags to sql database

Tags: php

This one is kind of complicated to explain but here we go

I have a text box sent up as an iframe so I can allow people to make their text bold or italic before submitting it to my database. I'm working in php and sql.

I've just discovered that if you were to enter a bunch of blank lines I get a bunch of

```
<br><br><br>
```

etc...' stored in the database.

I already have functions in place to strip out all unwanted html apart from paragraph and linebreak tags, and of course bold and italic, but what I now need is a function to check if the content is entirely html tags and no actual text inbetween them.

I've no idea how to go about this.

I'd like to allow something like '

```
<br> I am <br><br><br>
```

but not

```
<br> <br> <br>
```

or

```
<br> <br><br><br>
```

or something similar, empty tags or tags with just white space. How would I go about this?

I think I'm pretty clear on my problem without pasting any actual code as such, but I'm  but I'm happy to edit this if you want :)

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove all html tags and [trim](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) the remaining string. If nothing is left, there is no content:

```
if (empty(trim(strip_tags($your_string))))
{
  // no content
}
```

Comment: Hmm, this looks good and simple but for some reason whenever I add to my script it just leads to a white screen...then when commented out everything works again. I'm getting "PHP Fatal error:  Can't use function return value in write context in..." in my server error log? Anyone?

Comment: @MrC Just use a temporary variable: `$tmp = strip_tags($your_string); $tmp = trim($tmp); if (empty($tmp) {)`. Some functions don't accept functions as input parameters...